# Django objects.filter with args in loop

Tags: python, django

I search a way to optimize my Django's research function (in python). At this time I have this :

```
def search(acronym=None, name=None, reference=None):
    queryset = Organization.objects

    if acronym:
        queryset = queryset.filter(acronym=acronym)

    if name:
        queryset = queryset.filter(name=name)

    if reference:
        queryset = queryset.filter(reference=reference)

    return queryset
```

The problem is, each time I add an argument, I have to add an if + filter, etc.
There is a way to put this in a loop ?

For example :

```
  def search(acronym=None, name=None, reference=None):
    queryset = Organization.objects
    for arg in args : 
        if arg :
            queryset = queryset.filter(arg = arg)
    return queryset
```

or something like that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would `def search(**kwargs)`...`queryset.filter(**kwargs)` work?.. (I haven't time atm to test it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `**kwargs` in your function definition and filter out `None` valued items using a *dictionary comprehension* before passing and *unpacking* the named arguments to `filter`:

```
def search(**kwargs):
    kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v}
    queryset = Organization.objects.filter(**kwargs)
    return queryset
```